# JQueryMobile: Increase font-size in Header without incresing the height of the Header height

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to increase the font-size of the text in the JQM data-role=header tag without allowing JQM to increase the height of the header bar from its normal (20px?)

JQM seems to be calculating the height for the bar based on the font-size of the child nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/Z2saQ/

Click the button to see that page 2 is different and works per your question.

I just set the `.ui-header` class of `#page2` to a static 41px tall.

Then set the `h1` to something larger like 2em.